# Can someone provide references to understand the Schwinger Model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

I am starting to study the [Schwinger model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_model) for my thesis and I would like to get a better insight/intuition into it, do you have any good references?

I would like very complete references more than just quick summaries, thanks!

Comment: Well, there are always the original papers, linked in the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_model). (I think that's what you're talking about.)

Comment: I was having difficulties following those but yeah definetly I'll keep them close, for when I feel ready!

Comment: Schwinger et al. wrote a book on electromagnetism, called "Classical Electrodynamics," and it is quite an interesting book. It was not widely adopted because he insisted on carrying around magnetic monopole terms in his equations (there are no magnetic monopoles in real life AFAWK). But it is a good book nevertheless. Probably you should pick it up to understand his thoughts on classical EM before jumping into QED.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know that thanks, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just spent the last two months studying this model so I think I might have some useful information for you :)

Well, first of all as @march said, obviously the paper that started it all: [Gauge Invariance and Mass. II, J. Schwinger](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.128.2425)

But maybe before you can really follow it, you should first read chapter 19 on: [Peskin and Schroeder, An Introduction to quantum field theory](http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/483/Peskin,%20Schroesder%20-%20An%20introduction%20To%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory(T).pdf) (The axial current in two dimensions)

And then finally I would also check chapter 7 on: [David Tong, Lectures on Gauge Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) (QFT in 2Dimensions), and maybe other chapters aswell where he speaks about the $\theta$ term as a background field.

Comment: I was just checking the Peskin right now, seems a very good start, way better than those 60 years old papers! I'll also check the David Tong Lectures after this thanks!